# Loading External SVG file into SVGJS (Duplicate SVG Tag)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, svg.js

I am trying to load up an SVG file into svg.js.
My problem is that svg.js generates the svg tag and when I import my svg it ends up with 2 SVG tags which is causing collisions.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
Vue.prototype.$SVG = SVG;
```

template

```
  <div>
    <button @click="importSVG">import</button>
    <div ref="drawing"></div>
  </div>
```

```
  data() {
    return {
      svgFile: require("../assets/cassete.svg")
    };
  },
   importSVG() {
      fetch(this.svgFile)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(svg => {
          var tempEl = this.$refs.drawing;
          var draw = this.$SVG()
            .addTo(tempEl)
            .size('100%', '100%');

          draw.svg(svg);
          console.log(svg);


          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(svg, "application/xml");
          console.log(xmlDoc);
        });
    }
```

The result comes down to SVG.JS generating a svg tag and one already included in my svg file.

Would the best option be to just cherry pick the elements via the xml tree?

## Result

[image: Duplicate SVG tags]

Comment: what do you mean by collisions?

Comment: @RobertLongson Collisions as in, it changes the properties of the svg generated by svgjs leaving another svg tag with properties unaffected, so for example. if I change the size(width and height) it changes it in one svg tag(the one generated by svgjs) and not the other, leaving me with a svg that is oversized and cut out.

Comment: give the inner svg element a width and height of 100% then.

Answer (score 2):

You create an SVG and then add an SVG to it again (from your imported data)

You should just add your imported SVG directly to your Div:

```
  data() {
  return {
    svgFile:     require("../assets/cassete.svg")
  };
},
 importSVG() {
    fetch(this.svgFile)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(svg => {
        var tempEl = this.$refs.drawing;
        var draw = svg //this.$SVG()
          .addTo(tempEl)
          .size('100%', '100%');

      //draw.svg(svg);
      console.log(svg);


      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(svg, "application/xml");
      console.log(xmlDoc);
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.$SVG()` is a prototype of my main.js, `Vue.prototype.$SVG = SVG;` I can't leave that un-commented.

Comment: You had the right idea with what the problem is, thank you. I found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
    importSVG() {
      fetch(this.svgFile)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(svg => {
          var tempEl = this.$refs.drawing;

          var draw = this.$SVG(tempEl);
          draw.svg(svg);
        });
    }
```

As @Alex L said "You should just add your imported SVG directly to your Div"